# Not able to scroll within simulator

Tags: ruby, simulator

I'm writing an app using RubyMotion and the redpotion gem. I have a problem displaying the app with the simulator as it does not allow me to scroll within a tableView. It neither works when simulating an iPhone 6 nor an iPhone 4.

This is independent of the app. I have tried it also with my friend's app which works fine on his computer.

As I am not experienced enough to find out exactly what causes the problem I hope very much that somebody can help me resolving the problem.

Thanks, Daniel